# Endeless list demo

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

Im not following the getPendingView method. Shouldnt it be using the pending.xml layout instead of the row one???

> @Override
>       protected View getPendingView(ViewGroup parent) {
>         View row=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.**layout**.row, null);

```
  View child=row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

  child.setVisibility(View.GONE);

  child=row.findViewById(R.id.throbber);
  child.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  child.startAnimation(rotate);

  return(row);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldnt it be using the pending.xml layout instead of the row one?

No. `pending.xml` is used by the other demo activity.

> The text please wait...doesnt appear

It is not supposed to appear. Hence, it does not appear. The demo you are citing uses a rotating `ImageView` to indicate that something is pending.